# CL.exe error code

Tags: visual-studio, error-code

Has any of you got this error?

```
error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
```

I'm not able to find the meaning of the error code anywhere. I get it when building a C++ project in VS2013 Pro.

The project compiled fine in VS2010. I made no additional changes to it after updating VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. I changed the `Platform Toolset` from `Widnows SDK 7.1` to `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)`.